# Repeat crystal report header on new Tabs

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal reports, if I create a report and group by gender, I of course get a report which those "Males" and then "Females". If I click on the male group a new tab opens in crystal reports which has just the details of the male group.

My question is, is it possible that I can include the header and footer of my report in this new tab? I have seen ways to repeat the header but it goes on every single page. That is not my goal, I just want it to show in new tabs

Comment: Create one more group header and add a header on that section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File, Report Options...
Turn on the 'Show All Headers on Drill Down' option.